# Flutter chewie with custom controllers

Tags: flutter

in this [chewie](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie) library configs how can i hide `fullScreen`, `mute` and `time` parts from the controller?

```
VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
ChewieController _chewieController;

_videoPlayerController= VideoPlayerController.network(videoUrl);

_chewieController = ChewieController(
    videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    autoInitialize: true,
    autoPlay:true,
    looping: looping,
    errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('ERROR');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add

```
allowFullScreen: false,
allowMuting: false
```

to your `ChewieController` creation to disallow full screen and muting.

Or add

```
showControls: false
```

to completely hide the controls (including the time progress bar). This however also hides the play button.

Alternatively chewie gives you the option to define your own `customControls` for which you could use and edit the existing `MaterialControls` and `CupertinoControls` chewie uses [internally](https://github.com/brianegan/chewie/blob/master/lib/src/material_controls.dart).